# Is there a way to call an anonymous function from within itself in Kotlin?

Tags: recursion, kotlin, anonymous-function

I am trying to implement a method which would iterate over callbacks, however I have encountered a problem that I am unable to recursively call a function within itself.

The function currently looks like this:

```
fun <T : Any?, E : Any?> runSerial(
    transfer: T,
    callbacks: List<(T, (T) -> Unit, (E) -> Unit) -> Unit>,
    onSuccess: (T) -> Unit,
    onError: (E) -> Unit
) {
    val mutableCallbacks = callbacks.toMutableList()
    val runTopCallback = fun(value: T) {
        if (callbacks.count() == 0) {
            onSuccess(value)

            return
        }

        val nextCallback = mutableCallbacks.first()
        mutableCallbacks.remove(nextCallback)

        nextCallback(value, runTopCallback, onError)
    }

    runTopCallback(transfer)
}
```

Is there a way how to reword the code so that the `runTopCallback` can be passed to the `nextCallback` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) local variable (since Kotlin 1.2):

```
lateinit var runTopCallback: (T) -> Unit

runTopCallback = fun(value: T) {
    // ...

    nextCallback(value, runTopCallback, onError)
}
```

The problem is that `runTopCallback` has neither been declared nor defined at the point when you try to use it (because this is within a declaration + assignment statement).

The solution is to declare it first - the best way in this case is `lateinit`, which allows an initially valueless variable (hence the name, similar to a "null-initialized" variable), but without requiring null checks when it is used.

Comment: Thank you so much, Moira. Much appreciated your help! :)

Comment: @Andy glad I could help :)